# Remove the duplicate rows based on Presence of Number of NULL values in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was able to remove the duplicate rows, but I would like to remove the duplicate rows based on one more constraint. I want to keep only a row with a smaller number of NULL values.

Original Table

[image]

Ran the SQL Server Query

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT *,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Premise_ID ORDER BY Premise_ID)
   FROM sde.Premise_Test
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Result:

[image]

But I want to get this result

[image]

[image]

I have modified the SQL script  as per the comment from Aaron. but the result is still the same. DB fiddle is showing NULL from IS NULL getting highlighted.
[image]

Comment: Please provide table structure, sample data, and desired results in text (or [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk)) form, not images. Also see [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

Update the `ROW_NUMBER()` function like this (no, there is no shorter way):

```
RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY Premise_ID 
    ORDER BY Premise_ID,
         CASE WHEN Division IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
       + CASE WHEN InstallationType IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN OtherColumn IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       ...
)
```

Comment: I am still getting the same result. Not the desired one.

Comment: @accedesoft You're going to need to provide some more information, because Joel's answer works perfectly according to the requirements in your question, [as demonstrated in this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b1b4817411dd5943db8a573f0eaa6664).

Comment: One thing I have noticed in db fiddle that "NULL" from "IS NULL" is getting Highlighted. I have updated my screenshot.In the SQL environment the NULL part is not getting highlighted.

Comment: The colour formatting in DBFiddle is irrelevant, it's not as comprehensive or sophisticated as SSMS; the solution works perfectly, as you can no doubt see.